# Cannot see Segment in MixPanel when using Java

Tags: java, mixpanel, segment

I have segment working and sending events to MixPanel using javascript.
Now we want to do it using Java.
I tried to follow the example on 
https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/java/#selecting-integrations
Copying from the link above, I added, similarly, to my code, the snippets:

```
Analytics analytics = Analytics.builder(writeKey).build();
analytics.enqueue(IdentifyMessage.builder()
    .userId("f4ca124298")
    .traits(ImmutableMap.builder()
        .put("name", "Michael Bolton")
        .put("email", "mbolton@initech.com")
        .build()
    )
);
analytics.enqueue(TrackMessage.builder("Item Purchased")
    .userId("f4ca124298")
    .properties(ImmutableMap.builder()
        .put("revenue", 39.95)
        .put("shipping", "2-day")
        .build()
    )
);
analytics.flush()
```

The program is running correctly, but I cannot see any event on MixPanel. I am wondering what I might be doing wrong.

Is anyone able to assist?

Thank you in advance,

Thais.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to run it from a standalone java client? I faced similar issue when I was running from JUnit, however when I add a delay of a few seconds, it works.

So I am assuming segments is asynchronously posting messages to its server, when JVM shuts down before the message has been posted, we do not see any message but adding a delay works. Hope that helps.